# How to update / insert data in MySQL table via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in PHP .. I need help to make a PHP code to update data in MySQL if data exists and if don't already exists then insert data in MySQL.. I have made the PHP code to do this but it's inserting data when data already exists.. in MySQL.. Please help

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
$db  = mysql_select_db('gamingtracker',$con);
$query = "SELECT * FROM servers WHERE sgame='$game_insert'";
  $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
While($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$id = @$row['id']; 
$sname = @$row['sname']; 
$sgame = @$row['sgame']; 
$minplayers = @$row['minplayers']; 
$maxplayers = @$row['maxplayers']; 
$ip = @$row['ip']; 
$port = @$row['port']; 
$map = @$row['map'];
}



$sname1= html_entity_decode("{$server['s']['name']}");

      if(@$sname=="{$server['s']['name']}" 
      AND @$sgame=="{$server['s']['game']}" 
      AND @$minplayers=="{$server['s']['players']}" 
      AND @$maxplayers=="{$server['s']['playersmax']}" 
      AND @$ip=="{$server['b']['ip']}" 
      AND @$port=="{$server['b']['c_port']}" 
      AND @$map=="{$server['s']['map']}" ) 
      { 
  $query1 = "UPDATE servers
  SET sname='$sname1', sgame='{$server['s']['game']}', minplayers='{$server['s']['players']}', maxplayers='{$server['s']['playersmax']}', ip='{$server['b']['ip']}', port='{$server['b']['port']}', map='{$server['s']['map']}'
  WHERE ip='{$server['b']['ip']}', port='{$server['b']['port']}', sgame='{$server['s']['game']}'";
  $result1 = mysql_query($query1, $con);
  } 
      else { 
  $query1 = "INSERT INTO servers (id,sname,sgame,maxplayers,minplayers,ip,port,map) VALUES ('','$sname1','{$server['s']['game']}','{$server['s']['players']}','{$server['s']['playersmax']}','{$server['b']['ip']}','{$server['b']['c_port']}','{$server['s']['map']}')";
  $result1 = mysql_query($query1, $con);
  }
```

Comment: Why are you adding `@` everyhwere?

Comment: To dont give error ..if  the variable is empty

Comment: @u_mulder? help me plz..

Comment: @u_mulder: It really is about time that so-called 'functionality' was removed from PHP altogether.

Answer (score 0):

So you only want one entry per unique combination of ip, port, and sgame? The most straightforward way would be to let mysql handle this.

First, create a unique index on the table for those fields. Run the following in mysql:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ip_port_sgame ON servers (ip, port, sgame);
```

Then, instead of running an INSERT query, use REPLACE. So just change this one line in your php:

```
UPDATE servers
```

to

```
REPLACE INTO servers
```

Comment: i didnt understand this technique.. please explain further

Comment: Please help me.. Please explain further